# $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (x-y)^2$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of a simple property of real, constant functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113674/proof-of-a-simple-property-of-real-constant-functions)

> Suppose $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (x-y)^2$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Show f is differentiable.

This follows intuitively, the derivative $2(x-y)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. How do I show this formally?

Comment: "the derivative $2(x-y)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$" does not make any sense.

Comment: Hint: Let $x=a+h$ and $y=a$. Then $|f(a+h)-f(a)| \le h^2$.

Comment: This problem is easier than this one: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=142&cid=26&year=2007&sid=3d871034c4cf7613087eda8d1270dfa8 .

Comment: I restored the content of the question because it has two answers already, including one that is quite detailed.

Answer (score 5):

You can write this inequality as: $$-(x-y)^2\leq f(x)-f(y)\leq (x-y)^2$$ Assume that $x>y$. Then 
$$-(x-y)\leq \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\leq (x-y)$$Taking the limits as $x$ approaches $y$ and respecting the case $y>x$ you come to the conclusion that $f'(y)=0$ for all $y$. So, $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $h \to 0$ exists. In fact, the limit is zero. In order to show this, just begin with $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| \leq \dotsc$.

Answer (score 2):

> Then $f$ is constant (in particular, $f$ is differentiable).

To show this, consider $x\ne y$, split the interval between $x$ and $y$ into $n\geqslant1$ parts of length $|x-y|$ and apply the triangular inequality. This yields
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\left|f\left(x+\frac{k-1}n(y-x)\right)-f\left(x+\frac{k}n(y-x)\right)\right|.
$$
Now, apply the hypothesis to each of these intervals. The result is
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{|y-x|^2}{n^2}=\frac1n|y-x|^2.
$$
When $n\to\infty$, this proves that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Note that the same result holds as soon as $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant C|x-y|^a$ for every $x$ and $y$, for some $a\gt1$.

Comment: +1 for pointing it out. However, this seems simpler to me: Divide through by $(x-y)$, let $x \to y$ and conclude that $f' = 0$.

Comment: @t.b. One could argue that it is *easier* to avoid differentiation altogether.

Comment: Indeed, one could... :)

Comment: @t.b. Did you modify your first comment? I do not see the *easier* that was in it... :-)

Comment: Yes, I did, sorry about that; I submitted the edit more or less at the same time as your comment appeared and I thought the change wasn't important enough to try and reconstruct what exactly I wrote before.

Comment: @t.b. No worry, it was more to check I did not imagine the thing...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113674/24567). Read the description and the top response. That may give you a clue or two.